# HTML, free web editing tools

Tags: html, ide, frontpage

I am looking for a free web editing tools (IDE) for HTML editting, similar to frontpage 2003

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BlueGriffon](http://www.bluegriffon.org/) - Mozilla-based WYSIWYG editor, the successor of Mozilla Composer and Nvu (free, open-source).

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Express Product line - VS 2010 Web Developer Express http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-web-developer-express

Answer (score 1):

SeaMonkey is not too bad.   Not really an IDE though.